# How do I get the bug net?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I think this is related to (or the same question as:) [How do I get to Beedle's island at night?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42015/how-do-i-get-to-beedles-island-at-night), but the answers there don't really seem to answer the question.

Someone at the inn says that Beedle has a net I can buy, and that he's not there during the day.

I've tried going there at night, but I can't get to the bed (because it's under an outcropping, and my bird won't go in), and I can't see him out around during the day.

So, do I need to try harder to get to the bed on his island? Do I need to (wait until X occurs and) find him during the day?

Comment: Upgrade to the big bug net as soon as possible.  It makes catching things dramatically easier.

Comment: @splatteredbits Is it upgraded at the same shop?

Comment: No.  You upgrade in the Bazaar at the Scrap Shop, owned by Gondo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bug Net` is sold in Beedle's shop in Skyloft. Beedle's shop is the flying building that is making an orbit around the Bazaar in the daytime. You will need either the `Slingshot` or the `Beetle` to ring the bell and cause Beedle to lower the rope so you can get into the shop. It will cost 50 rupees once you get up there.

After getting it, speak to Gondo in the bazaar to see what treasures you will need to collect in order to upgrade it to the `Big Bug Net`, making it soooo much easier to catch things.

Comment: Thanks for the added info about its orbit around the bazaar.

Answer (score 9):

**Beedle** *sells* the **Bug Net** at his store.  You need to [get to his store in **Skyloft**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37223/how-do-you-get-beedles-airship-to-stop) during the day.  It will cost you **50 Rupees** to purchase it.

Comment: So, where is his store in Skyloft? Does it not open up until later, or have I missed it?

Comment: It's the floating building that you see flying around **Skyloft**.  It has a big bell hanging below it for you to shoot at.